# Connecting 36V LiIon packs in series to get ~120VDC to run lawn mower

Tags: bms, lithium-ion

I'm converting my electric plugin lawnmower to battery power.  I was able to get 3 used e-bike identical model 36V 5Ah packs (obviously not matched with respect to lifetime usage). Each pack has its own BMS (battery management system) built in.   I connected the packs in series to power the DC motor and measured 42V*3 = 126VDC when the packs are fully charged. The mower ran fine (4A idle current; 8A full-load) while cutting the grass last summer, except some times it would shut off (seemingly NOT dependent on motor load -- i.e. grass height). When shutting off, it would usually restart normally after waiting a minute or so.  I determined that if I partially charged the battery packs to about 40V instead of 42V (individual 36V chargers for each pack!), the shutdowns stopped happening.  But towards end of summer, one of the pack's BMS apparently went bad and that pack always measures 20V with my digital VOM (6V with my Simpson analogue meter).  The faulty pack does, however, draw the charger's rated 2A when connected to it, although the pack still never provides any current or voltage above 20V).

I presume I might have blown the BMS on the one pack? Its BMS might have shut that pack down due to undervoltage (3.0V/cell), but since the other 2 packs were still powering the mower, would the 80V or so appear across  the shutdown BMS and then permanently damage it?

I suppose I could design a relay circuit that would break the entire 3-pack series string when one pack shuts off via BMS.  But would the relay break the circuit fast enough to protect the BMS?   Alternatively, I could install analogue panel voltmeters on each pack to make sure all packs are well above cut-off voltage even under full motor load.   Thoughts/comments would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: "that pack always measures 20V with my digital VOM (6V with my Simpson analogue meter)." What is the voltage on that seemingly broken battery? 6V or 20V?

Comment: "The faulty pack does, however, draw the charger's rated 2A when connected to it, although the pack still never provides any current or voltage above 20V)." The charger tries to charge the battery even thought its dead. The correct recommendation would be to remove the bad batter altogether or replace it.